# export '__RouterContext' (imported as 's') was not found in 'react-router'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router

This is my error and I can't fix it :(((
This error appeared while I

```
import { GuardProvider, GuardedRoute } from 'react-router-guards'
```

and use it.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not expressly limited by `react-router-guard`'s `package.json` the repo and README both state there's a peer dependency on `react-router-dom@5`.

See [Requirements](https://github.com/upstatement/react-router-guards#requirements).

> This package has the following peer dependencies:
>
> - React v16.8.0+ (for hooks ⚓️)
> - React Router DOM v5.0.0+

Based on the error it seems you have `react-router-dom@6` installed and it has many different exports than the previous version. To resolve you will need to revert to the v5 version of `react-router-dom`.

To install, run from the project's root directory:

```
npm i -s react-router-dom@5
```